# Class variable C#

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose I have 3 classes namely: Class1, Class2 and class3.
Class3 has a variable `var3`.

Is it possible that `var3` (from Class3) can only be accessed by Class1 and not by Class2 or any other classes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another option in addition to the ones mentioned:

```
public class Class3
{
    private int var3;

    public class Class1
    {
        public void ShowVar3(Class3 instance)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(instance.var3);
        }
    }
}
```

Which option is the *right* one will depend on your context. I'd argue that whatever you do, you almost certainly shouldn't be trying to access another class's *variables* directly - but all of this applies to *members* as well, which is more appropriate.

Comment: @yonan2236: Right, although exactly the same principles will apply.

Answer (score 6):

Put `Class1` and `Class3` in the same assembly, and make `Class3` internal. Then it will only be visible to the other classes inside the same assembly.

Comment: This is likely the right answer to the OP's question, +1 for that. But perhaps the OP should reconsider their approach using inheritance or interfaces instead of a non-OOP way of 'rights management'.

Comment: @Bazzz - I totally agree with you here. There is something a bit awkward in the OP's architecture.

Answer (score 3):

If you make var3 protected for class3 and make class1 inherit from class3 it'll work

**Edited, when its a property**

Eg:

```
public class Class3
{
     protected int Var3 {get;set;}
}


public class Class2
{
}


public class Class1 : Class3
{
   //access Var3 here
}
```